# Accessing class variables in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, class-variables

What is the correct syntax for storing something in my class variable from a view ? Let's say that this is the code:

**Controller:**

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
@@myvar = "I'm a string"

*
*
*
methods
*
*
*
end
```

**Form:**

```
<%= form_for(@something) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :myvar %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This is just an example of a form as it is not functional, I cannot find what the correct syntax is for accesssing `@@myvar` from the view. Thanks !

Comment: that is a very very bad approach and should never be done in rails! please tell us why you need that and we find a better solution!

Comment: btw: form_for object opens a block with the "f" as the identifier of the object.  object is an object of a model, not of a controller

Comment: Well, I'd like to have a kind of temporary variable within a controller to do some stuff which would recieve the data from a form and I'm not so skilled in rails so I couldn't come up with another approach, that's why I came up with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**as on request i edited, including attr_accessor**

Rails way. Ill just fly over, hope you get it. you defenitely need to read more introductions to rails and its concept.

you have a rails-model, lets call it Animal

```
class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :non_saved_variable

end
```

this is having a database-table, lets say in this table we store race, name and age.

now we need a controller, to create/edit/update/delete animals

```
class AnimalController < ActionController::Base
   def new
     # this creates a new animal with blank values
     @animal = Animal.new
   end
end
```

now you need to go into your routes.rb and create a route for animals

```
resources :animal
```

this will create all (restful) routes for every actions of an animal.

now you need to have your template to render a form

form_for is a rails helper, to create a form, associated with the @animal (which is a new Animal). You pass |f| into the block, so with f you can access the form

```
=form_for @animal do |f|
```

then you can go for each field you need to call another rails helper
you can also access attr_accessors.

```
=f.text_field :race
=f.text_field :name
=f.text_field :age
=f.text_field :non_saved_variable
```

by that you get the  stuff

dont fortget `f.submit` because your form needs a submit button

if you now click on your button, the form will be posted to the create method of rails. so you need to bring it into your controller

```
def create
   # create a new animal with the values sended by the form
   @animal = Animal.new params[:animal]

   # here you can access the attr_accessor
   @animal.do_something if @animal.non_saved_variable == "1337"

   if @animal.save
     # your animal was saved. you can now redirect or do whatever you want
   else
     #couldnt be saved, maybe validations have been wrong
     #render the same form again
     render action: :new
   end
end
```

i hope that gave you a first insight of rails ?!

Comment: I understand the principles of these things, I don't know how to achieve what I wrote up there on the comment. Creating a variable which will get something from the view and do things with it without it being in the actual database since that isn't required.

Comment: if you dont want that to be in database, then you go attr_accessor. ill edit my post

Comment: attr_accessor can be used for values you don't want to store in the database directly and that will only exist for the life of the object (e.g. passwords).

Comment: That is something that I was looking for. How about accessing the attr again in the controller ? E.g. I want to do something with that value before the object is saved, is that possible ?

Comment: yes you can do something with the value. ill edit it again

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I was looking for, thanks for the extensive help !

Answer (score 2):

DO NOT DO THIS

You can get or set class variables from any class by:

```
<%= FooController.class_variable_get(:@@myvar) %>
<%= FooController.class_variable_set(:@@myvar, 'value') %>
```

This is probably not what you want. Do not do it. What are you trying to achieve?

DO THIS INSTEAD:

If it's a variable that you want to be available to all actions in that controller consider an instance variable set in a a before filter:

```
class FooController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :set_var

  private
    def set_var
      @my_var = "I'm a string"
    end
end
```

Then in your view, just call `<%= @my_var %>`

Comment: How could I store something into that variable from a form like that one in my post ?